# How to full recover from a external hard drive with a password?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, acronis-trueimage

When I tried to recover using Acronis True Image it didn't work and I think I know why. The external hard drive the backups are on doesn't mount until the user enters a password. How do I get around this? The external hard drive is a Western Digital Passport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing WD Security, it gives the option to disable password protection. Doing this will allow Acronis to recover from backups on it, even after restarting the computer.